# UWP - How do I scan my local network to see which devices are connected?

Tags: windows-10, uwp

I want to see which IP a specific IoT device has in my network, so I can connect to it with an app. I found example on how to scan for WiFi networks, but I haven't really found anything find devices in a specific network.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Windows.Devices.Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225459) classes also to enumerate devices over networks (not only locally devices). But looks that you need establish connection to each network (one by one).

Still same method [DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.findallasync.aspx) should give you also devices in network. You can limit devices search with filter.
Here is article about:  [Enumerate devices over a network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enumerate-devices-over-a-network)